# Laravel & multiple count queries using Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to optimise my code wherein I generate stats over the last seven days.

Presently I'm using eloquent & querying counts for recorded data for each day, this causes me to make 7 seperate queries within a loop.

example:

```
// loop for number of days
for($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++){
    // some logic to set comparitive unix times
    $oldest = $newest - $dayDuration;

    // count number of objects between oldest time and newest time
    $counts[$i] = Object::where('objecttime','>',$oldest)
                          ->where('objecttime','<',$newest)->count();

    // more logic to set comparitive unix times
    $newest = $newest - $dayDuration;
}
```

I know that one can group queries in sql using similar syntax as described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-to-make-multiple-counts-in-one-query); what I would like to know is if it is possible to do the same using eloquent/fluent in Laravel, or is it only possible to do this using raw queries?

EDIT: I don't know if I need to clarify, but this is a Laravel 3 question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you call a static method on your model class, it returns a Fluent query like `DB::table('yourmodeltable')->method`. If you keep that in mind, you will soon realize it's possible to do any query with Eloquent models.

Now, to achieve greater performance, you can use SQLs [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html) function. My example below is untested, so feel free to correct it please.

```php
// tomorrow -1 week returns tomorrow's 00:00:00 minus 7 days
// you may want to come up with your own date tho
$date = new DateTime('tomorrow -1 week');

// DATE(objecttime) turns it into a 'YYYY-MM-DD' string
// records are then grouped by that string
$days = Object::where('objecttime', '>', $date)
    ->group_by('date')
    ->order_by('date', 'DESC') // or ASC
    ->get(array(
        DB::raw('DATE(`objecttime`) AS `date`'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`')
    ));

foreach ($days as $day) {
    print($day->date . ' - '. $day->count);
}
```

This should print something like:

```
2013-03-09 - 13
2013-03-10 - 30
2013-03-11 - 93
2013-03-12 - 69
2013-03-13 - 131
2013-03-14 - 185
2013-03-15 - 69
```

**Edit:**

The suggested approach above returns instances of Eloquent Model, which may seem weird, specially if you `var_dump($days)`. You can also use Fluent's `list()` method to achieve the same thing.

```php
$date = new DateTime('tomorrow -1 week');

// lists() does not accept raw queries,
// so you have to specify the SELECT clause
$days = Object::select(array(
        DB::raw('DATE(`objecttime`) as `date`'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`')
    ))
    ->where('created_at', '>', $date)
    ->group_by('date')
    ->order_by('date', 'DESC') // or ASC
    ->lists('count', 'date');

// Notice lists returns an associative array with its second and
// optional param as the key, and the first param as the value
foreach ($days as $date => $count) {
    print($date . ' - ' . $count);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, let me give that a bash and report back.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the query I finally used. Thanks again Vinícius.

Comment: group_by() and order_by() didn't work for me. I had to use groupBy() and orderBy().